# In which database table is the list of files attached to a node?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-database

I have a Drupal 7 website. My goal is to transfer Drupal website data to another CMS. So I need data like names of files(list of files) attached to each post, images, text content, category and published date each post.

I find any data in database for each node like images, text content, category, published date for each node (with search in database by `navicat` tools). But I cant find names of files attached to each post( list of files attached to a node).

For example when I enter `mywebsite.com/news/135` in Web browser, Web browser display to me a post with text content and tree image and five PDF files attached ( I find text content and tree image in database for node=135 but cant find list of files attached for node=135 ).

I want know list of files attached for the node id is 135.

Note: I know data of all my files uploaded store in `media_field_data` and `file_manage` tables. But this tables don't have data about this files where used or which node used this files.

I try three day search in the website database (by navicat) But I haven't found it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found tables have  list of files attached to a node.

The below tables have relation about which files used in any node:

1. paragraphs_item_field_data
2. field_news_body_target_id
3. media_field_data
4. node__field_media_photo
5. media_field_data
6. file_manage

Note: Maybe `field_news_body_target_id` is different with your table database.